# how to make visualforce view fields align horizontally?

Tags: visualforce, fields

Help me I have this
[image]

I need this
[image]

Here is my code:

```
    <apex:pageBlock tabStyle="Account_Search__tab" title="Search Criteria">      
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
           <apex:inputField value="{!account.Name}" required="false"/> 
           <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingCountry}"/> 
           <apex:inputField value="{!account.Industry}"/>    
           <apex:inputField value="{!account.Type}"/>           
           <!-- <apex:commandButton action="{!}" value="Find Accounts"/> -->
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Ralph, with your latest edit it has become quite unclear what your question is or how the previous given answers relate to it. Could you consider undoing your edit and extending your question rather than replacing it ?

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke if you vote down those two answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the columns attribute from [apex:pageBlockSection](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockSection.htm)

The documentation for columns is:

> The number of columns that can be included in a single row of the page
>   block section. Note that a single column spans two cells - one for a
>   field's label, and one for its value. If you use child inputField,
>   outputField, or pageBlockSectionItem components in the
>   pageBlockSection, each of the child components is displayed in one
>   column, spanning both cells. If you use any other components in the
>   pageBlockSection, each of the child components is displayed in one
>   column, displaying only in the rightmost cell of the column and
>   leaving the leftmost column cell blank. While you can specify one or
>   more columns for a pageBlockSection, Salesforce stylesheets are
>   optimized for either one or two columns. If not specified, this value
>   defaults to 2.

The value defaulting to 2 is why you are seeing 2 columns in your page. If you set this attribute to the number of fields you have then you will get your desired output.

You will also need two apex:pageBlockSection. One for the labels and one for the input fields. What is shown below should do what you need.

```
<apex:pageBlock tabStyle="Account_Search__tab" title="Search Criteria">
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4">
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Name.Label}"/>
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.BillingCountry.Label}"/>
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Industry.Label}"/>  
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Type.Label}"/>         
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4">
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.Name}" required="false" label=""/> 
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingCountry}" label=""/> 
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.Industry}" label=""/>    
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.Type}" label=""/>           
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

The above page is making use of:

- [apex:pageBlockSection](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockSection.htm)
- [apex:outputLabel](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputLabel.htm)
- [apex:inputField](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm)
- [$ObjectType](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_objecttype.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding  `columns="4"` in your `<apex:pageBlockSection>` :

```
<apex:pageBlock tabStyle="Account_Search__tab" title="Search Criteria">      
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4">
           <apex:inputField value="{!account.Name}" required="false"/> 
           <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingCountry}"/> 
           <apex:inputField value="{!account.Industry}"/>    
           <apex:inputField value="{!account.Type}"/>           
           <!-- <apex:commandButton action="{!}" value="Find Accounts"/> -->
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: I tried that but then it does not look like what I need.

Comment: What did you get ?

Comment: It became horizontal but the labels did not go above the fields.

Comment: How do you put the labels ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use plain HTML table block to achieve this. This can ensure full control of ui rendering and spacing to you and would also avoid any unwanted pageblocksection's ui spacing (pageblocksection supports more than two columns but UI is not good)

..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by wrapping your `<apex:inputField>` inside of an `<apex:outputPanel>` and `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>`. See example below:

```
<apex:pageBlock tabStyle="Account_Search__tab" title="Search Criteria">      
  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4">

    <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Name.label}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.Name}" required="false"/> 
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.BillingCountry.label}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingCountry}"/> 
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Industry.label}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.Industry}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
    </apex:outputPanel>  

    <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Type.label}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.Type}"/>  
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:outputPanel>     

  </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

I stumbled upon this solution by accident, not sure if it's a recommended way.